# Taking Putnam as a freshman.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

Currently, in 11th grade, I've always thong about participating exams like the Putnam.

I have however, sent the problems, and they seem, to be grueling hard!!

I have access to problem solving strategies by Engel, as well as Putnam and Beyond by Titu.

But they don't seem to have anything similar to the actual content of Putnam.

So, how should I prepare? I can try previous Putnam exams, but would that TEACH me anything?? Thanks!

Comment: You could do a lot worse than find a copy of Kedlaya, Poonen, & Vakil, [*The William Lowell Putnam Mathematical Competition $1985$-$2000$: Problems, solutions and Commentary*](http://www.amazon.com/William-Lowell-Mathematical-Competition-1985-2000/dp/0883858274). In many cases you get multiple solutions, and the solutions are thorough, generally pointing out key ideas clearly. \\ Yes, it’s worth trying some old Putnam problems; I’d concentrate on the first two in each section, since they’re the easiest.

Comment: You can also ask your local university's math dept if they have a Putnam mentor, - someone who goes over and prepares students for the upcoming Putnam examination. These individuals are quite common these days.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott, thanks a lot. But will they first help me learn the material? Thanks Brian Scott, you are great!

Comment: @Amad27: You’re very welcome. It really depends on how much you already know: if you already have the necessary background for a problem, the solutions and discussions can teach you quite a bit. If not, you probably won’t get a lot out of the discussion, other than an indication of an area that you might want to learn about.

Comment: You might want to go through this link https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1b5m7Wb07z_faWDWS_Yv1359n_bdIMEj7 and try your hand. I have three of the books @BrianM.Scott is talking about as well as a few others that are related to Putnam. Happy hunting!